# in which cases do I need to lock a variable from simultaneous access?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

In a C or C++ program, if 2 threads use the same global variable, then you need to lock the var via a mutex.

But in which cases exactly?

1. Thread 1: read Thread 2: read
2. Thread 1: write Thread 2: read
3. Thread 1: write Thread 2: write

Of course you need to lock at case 3 but what is with the other 2 cases? What happens at case 2 (with non atomic operations)? Is there some kind of access violation or does Thread 2 just get the old value? I'm a litle confused about this, because memory and registers on the hardware level can't be accessed at the same time (in normal PC hardware) or do we have some kind of parallel CPUs with parallel bus lines to parallel ram chips?

Comment: Cases 2 and 3, i.e. any situation in which at least one thread is writing with at least one other thread reading or writing.

Comment: You don't always need to lock when accessing data from different threads. Look at atomic operations, and especially at C++11's `std::atomic`

Comment: And yes, to address your last sentence, on multicore CPUs there can be multiple copies of each value in the various levels of cache.

Comment: (which may or may not be shared between cores)

Comment: Also, be aware that something that fits neatly into one register and the operation on it can be completed in one CPU cycle on one hardware, may easily take multiple cycles on another one.

Comment: You're missing an important sub-case: `read-modify-write`. On both threads, so your matix is a lot bigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just think of what may happen in each of the cases. Let's only consider the race condition: it's easy and it's enough for us to see the consequences.

In case 1, the variable is not being modified, so no matter which the order is, both threads will read the same value. So basically, nothing is wrong here.

Cases 2 and 3 are worse. Let's say you have a race condition, and don't know which of the threads will get access earlier. That means:

For case 2: The value of the variable in the end of all operations is fine (it will be the value written by Thread 1), but Thread 2 may get an old value of the variable, which may cause a crash, or other problems.

For case 3: The end value of the variable is not predictable, since it depends on which thread will perform the write operation last.

For cases 2 and 3, it may also happen that one of the threads will try to access the variable while it is in an inconsistent state, and you may end up with some rubbish data read by one of the threads (i.e. Case 2), or even rubbish data in the variable after completion of all operations.

So yea, lock for cases 2 and 3.

Comment: Case 2 can be quite bad: the variable might be in an inconsistent state when read by thread 2.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yea that's true (for case 3 also), but I didn't mention it not to over-complicate the answer. Should I add it to the answer then, or leave it as it is?

Comment: I think it is necessary to add this to the answer, it is the main issue with non-atomic operations. Your answer seems to imply atomicity. Also, note that locking will not guarantee any particular access order.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the threads actually access the variable at the same time. The rule is that if another thread could have modified the variable at some point, then the reading thread must use sync instruction of some kind (a lock). Without a sync instruction there is, by definition, a race condition. Even if the CPU has no access at the same time, without a sync instruction there's no guarantee that you see any values written by another thread.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, or at least misleading.  Case 2 is undefined behavior.  It's not a question of just getting a stale value, anything can happen.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y You need synchronization on both the read and the write.  Recall that the writes may not be atomic and as a result one thread could get half-way through its write before the second thread starts (and finishes) its write.  You could end up with some strange half-and-half value.  More formally, undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for locking are simple:

> If you write to a variable, concurrently accessed by another thread, then you need proper sequencing of operations (for example, via locking).

With this simple rule, we can easily evaluate each of the cases:

1. No write, no need for synchronization
2. Write, concurrent access, need synchronization
3. Write, concurrent access, need synchronization

And what happen if you don't lock ?

Well, formally, this is *undefined behavior*. Meaning that we don't know. Which while though the only possible response does help grasping the extent of the issue.

At the machine level, what may happen is either:

- in case of read: access to a stale value
- in case of read: access to a partial value (only half is updated at the time you look)
- in case of write: the final value is a hodgepodge (at bit-level) of the values

... and let's not forget that whenever you read an incorrect pointer/size it may lead to a crash.

At the compiler level, the compiler may optimize *as if* the thread was having sole access. In this case it may mean:

- removing "redundant" reads: transform `while (flag)` into `if (flag) while (true)`...
- removing "unused" writes
- ...

The presence of memory fences and explicit synchronization instructions (which the use of mutexes introduce) prevent those optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is simple: if an object is accessed (read or write) by
more than one thread, and is modified by any thread, then *all*
accesses need to be synchronized.  Otherwise, you have undefined
behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite as simple as it may seem, except for two cases:

1. When there are only readers and no writers, you do **not** need to synchronize, ever.
2. When there are several threads writing and at least one of them is performing a read-modify-write operation (such as `++x;`) you **always** need to synchronize, or you'll get totally unpredictable results.

In all other cases, if you have *at least one writer* and a reader (or several writers), you **usually** (with very few exceptions) need to synchronize access, but not necessarily always, and not always in the strictest possible way.

It very much depends on what guarantees you need. Some applications need strict sequential consistency over threads (and sometimes you even need lock fairness). Some applications will work equally well, but with much better performance, if they only have happens-before guarantees within the same thread. Yet other applications do not even need that much and are entirely happy with relaxed operations or without any guarantees at all.

For example, this "typical" implementation of a worker thread has a writer and a reader:

```
// worker thread
running = true;
while(running) { task = pull_task(); execute(task); }

// main thread exit code
running = false;
join(workerthread);
```

This works perfectly well without any synchronization. Yes, pedantically speaking it is undefined when or how the value of `running` will change, but in reality it makes no difference. There is no way the memory location could have some "random" intermediate value, and it doesn't really matter whether the change gets visible a few dozen nanoseconds earlier or later because the worker thread will most likely be busy executing a task anyway, and in the worst case it picks up the change a few milliseconds later. Eventually, on the next iteration, the worker thread *will* pick up the change and will exit.
The SPSC fast-forward queue published in Dr. Dobb's some years ago worked on a similar principle, only with pointers.

A good and comprehensive read on the many different synchronization modes and their implications is given in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync).