# Multithreading with a global variable: if only one thread is changing the variable, is it necessary to lock it?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

As titled, several thread accessing one variable, and only one thread will change the variable, and all the others will just read its value. Like this:

**Thread 1**:

```
while True:
    a += 1
```

**Thread 2, 3, 4,...**:

```
print a
```

In this case, only Thread 1 is changing variable `a`. Will any serious problems happen?

I found a similar C/C++ tagged question titled "[***in which cases do I need to lock a variable from simultaneous access?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016806/in-which-cases-do-i-need-to-lock-a-variable-from-simultaneous-access)", and it seems from the answer, that the only thing I need to worry about is that the `a` acquired from the other thread might not be as updated.

I'm asking, other than that I might not get the newest a value, is it possible something more serious will happen and crush the code if I don't lock the variable while accessing it?

I don't think this is language related, but if it matters, I'm specifically interested in the case for Python.

Comment: As long as no race conditions can occur for the specific variable, then there shouldn't be a need to lock it.

Comment: No problems. Each thread will get the newest value at the point in time where they read it.

Comment: @JacobG. Integers are immutable in Python. The statement `a+=1` creates a new integer and changes `a` to refer to it.

Comment: ...except... classes implement `+=` with the `__iadd__` method. For integers you are safe. But mutable containers may act oddly. Suppose this was a list and you are extending it. Another thread iterating it may have problems. For instance, `len(somelist)` followed by `for i in somelist` may iterate more items.

Comment: @tdelaney. No, the threads may not necessarily get the "newest value" at the time they read it. Different caches may have different versions of the value. All that can be guaranteed is that the thread won't get an older version of the variable than the version that it had read previously. So if thread 1 set `a` to 1, then 2, then 3, 4, 5, and thread 2 read the value 2 from `a`, then the next time thread 2 reads a value, it will be either 2,3,4, or 5, but not 1. And then there's another problem--if `a` isn't altered atomically, thread 2 can read a weird value if it reads while thread 1 writes.

Comment: @rsjaffe are you referring to CPU level cache coherency or perhaps memory barriers for out-of-order memory operations?

Comment: @rsjaffe In cpython at least, you don't have simultaneous access to python variables. Only one byte code operation is running in a process at a time. Python will wake other threads that are waiting on the global interpreter lock but if I remember my cache coherency rules properly, that ensures you won't get stale data. byte code atomicity is why I hedged my bets in previous comments.

Comment: I was assuming true multithreading. The "newest value" comment refers to cache coherency. If it's just running them as coroutines on a single-threaded interpretor, you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: @rsjaffe Where can I find the guarantee that a thread can't get an older version than the version it had read previously? Is in the python specification? If so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, how catastrophic a problem it would be would depend on what the consequences were of one of the other threads obtaining the wrong value.

The answer may indeed be computer-language related: See the [**Software** section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) in the general Wikipedia article on [***Race condition***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Related to that is the fact that, thanks to the "[GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock)", for the most part Python programs don't do real multithreading since the interpreter isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Does this mean that since python has a GIL, so it's safe in python to operate in this way because it will lock the variable in default anyway?

Comment: @beedrill: In your trivial example code, yes. Updating a more complex type might not however, because the GIL might be released and reacquired during the update process. Note that creating and using a `threading.Lock` to prevent concurrent access problems is super easy in Python: i.e.: a `with my_lock:` will acquire the lock before and release it after the following suite of statements execute.

Answer (score -2):

Irrespective of the language, updating a variable by two separate threads will affect the value.  But printing the values will not.  The only issue is all the threads (2 onwards) will print different values.

Think this is happening in a database.  One person can update the dB, but many can read it.

Comment: This is not true. For example, imagine if `a+=1` is implemented as follows: 1) Store the value of `a`. 2) Destroy the `a` object. 3) Create a new integer object with the value we stored plus 1. 4) Make `a` refer to that new object. -- Now, what happens if another thread tries to access the value of `a` after step 1 but before step 4?

Comment: This is not the way in which the languages are implemented.  a+= 1, will work as follows:
The value of a is copied to the register of the processor.  It will be incremented by 1 and a will be updated.  a is residing in the main memory of the computer.  The increment is happening at the register level.  The register value will be written back to the memory location of a.
When another thread is accessing the value of a between these 3 steps, it will get the old value of a.  No other reading threads can CHANGE the value of a.
In no way a will be "destroyed" as claimed by you

Comment: Do you mean some languages happen to be implemented that way? Or do you mean all languages are guaranteed to be implemented that way? If the former, isn't is crazy to rely on that? If the latter, where can I find such a marvelous, broad guarantee documented? (And how do you know all computers for all time will even have registers? Or are you suggesting that it's okay to write code that might fail when a person upgrades their CPU?)

Comment: I think the question is about normal computer usage.  If a person is using a normal computer which has an intel processor, a+=1 is implemented as I said.  Please refer to any "Computer Organization" course material. 

From wikipedia "Almost all computers, whether load/store architecture or not, load data from a larger memory into registers where it is used for arithmetic operations and is manipulated or tested by machine instructions. Manipulated data is then often stored back to main memory, either by the same instruction or by a subsequent one. "

Comment: No, absolutely not! The question is about python, a language that has a specification that allows you to write code that will work correctly no matter what CPU, operating system, or library it happens to run on.

Comment: If you can show the implementation of a+=1 like you told in any other platform by python your argument is correct.  What I told, is the usual way of implementing it.  

If you cannot show that implementation, there is no point in arguing on this.  Thanks for the "nice" discussion

Comment: No, sorry, no. When you write code in python, you're writing python. The whole point of having a language with a specification and with rules is that you can write code that works correctly without having to understand the details of any particular implementation. "It works on every implementation I know or can imagine" does not make it correct. "It follows the rules for the language" makes it correct. It is almost negligent to train programmers to write code that "happens to work" when there is absolutely no difficulty writing code that is guaranteed to work by the relevant specifications.